# How would I write a scanf() statement that only accepts certain characters?

Tags: c, logic, boolean-logic

For a program I'm writing, I need to use `scanf()` to only scan in characters that are between 0-9, A-Z, and a-z.

I figured I could use some nice comparison operators to help me accomplish my goal. For example, maybe this could work:

```
int i = 3;
char a[7] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '?', 'e', 'f', '\0'};

if (!(a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9') && !(a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'Z') && !(a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z'))
  printf("not 0-9. A-Z, or a-z!\n");
```

In other words, if the character in `a[i]` is not a digit or a letter, then print the statement. But, that didn't work. Any alternatives?

Comment: How about checking the C standard library. Start with `ctype.h`.

Answer (score 2):

C standard library provides functions for testing characters to be a [digit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html) or a [letter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isalpha.html):

```
if (!isalpha(a[i]) && !isdigit(a[i])) {
    printf("Not a letter or a digit\n");
}
```

You need to include `<ctype.h>` in order to reference these functions.

Comment: Or simply `if(!isalnum(a[i]))`. Though given the title of the question, it might be about `%[A-Za-z0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

edited per the comments:

to have scanf() only input certain characters, you could try:

```
char buffer[100] = {'\0'};
if( 1 != scanf( "%99[0-9A-Za-z]", buffer ) )
{ // scanf failed -- EOF or I/O error
     perror( "scanf failed" );
     exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

the question does not discuss if input is to continue after encountering a 'non desired' character nor how to handle 'non desired' characters so I will not presume to second guess the problem scenario.

which could input up to 99 characters but would stop if encountering any character other than 0...9, A...Z. a...z.

Answer (score 1):

To use `scanf()` to accept only certain characters, define  a scan set with `"%[]"`

```
char dest[80];

if (scanf("%79[0-9A-Za-z]", dest) == 1) {
  printf("Success.%s.\n", dest);
} else {  
  puts("Fail");
  fgetc(stdin);  // Consume non-matching character.
}
```